# Using rest services vs database scripts for database cleanup

Tags: database, rest

In our project we have multiple components(java based apps) interacting with each other and have delete rest API's to clean up the data. All the apps use same MSSQL database with different schema.

We need to clean up around 50K data, I believe preparing a script to clean up the data is best approach since using REST service will put stress and time consuming.

Any suggestion on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

If both solutions are equal, and this is a one-off task pick the one that's easiest. If both solution are not equal, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always a fan of automating a need i.e. if a need arises today, it is bound to arise again. For this specific case i.e. 50K you're going to require a script that will run and delete the all the 50K rows in question using business rules f and logic as validation for the delete.

On the other hand, you might want to invest in a Service for future similar requests that will require a similar delete. The good thing about having a service is that you can always call it from anywhere, where as a script has go to be run or triggered from within a certain environment.

I hope it helps.